# window.addEventListener("message") not working in salesforce mobile app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, aura, debugging, javascript-debugging

I have an **Aura component** that opens a **canvas app**.
The *canvas app* communicates with the *Aura component* using `window.postMessage`.

In my Aura component during `init`, I am adding a listener for `postMessage`.

The listener works perfectly in a browser but in a `salesforce1 app`, The callback is not working.

Is there a limitation that prevents using postMessage on mobile devices?

Since Simulating salesforce1 app from **/one/one.app** from the browser does not work anymore. So I'm using alerts to debug on a mobile device, is there a better way to debug it for salesforce1 app?

***sample.cmp***

```
<aura:component controller="SampleCtrl" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId">
     <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

     <force:canvasApp developerName="{!v.connectedAppName}" parameters="{!v.appUrl}" width="{!v.width}" height="infinite" maxWidth="{!v.width}"/> 
</aura:component>
```

sampleController.js

```
({
    init: function (cmp, evt, hlp) {
        hlp.addPostMessageListner(cmp);
    }
});
```

***sampleHelper.js***

```
   addPostMessageListner: function(cmp) {
        alert("adding listner");
        window.addEventListener("message", $A.getCallback(function(event) { 
            //this line is not running in mobile device but works in browser
            alert("Got message"); 
            // Perform some logic
        }));
    },
```

Comment: Can it be targetOrigin issues? so that URL's are not the same in the app as in the web? In here they do not say anything about mobile https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_postmessage.htm but gives info about postmessage.